# oAuth2.0 for google drive C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, google-drive-api

Everytime I connect to the google drive it throws WebException 401 Unauthorized.

```
   WebClient wC = new WebClient();
   var down = wC.DownloadString("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/about?includeSubscribed=true&key=[api-key]");
   JObject o = JObject.Parse(down);

   Console.WriteLine("Name, " +o["name"]);
   Console.ReadLine();
```

I want to create C# Desktop Application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code

```
   UserCredential credential;
        try
        {                
            using (var stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "client_secrets.json"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    new[] { DriveService.Scope.DriveFile, DriveService.Scope.Drive },
                    acocuntAddress, CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("Drive.Auth.Store")).Result;

            }               
            var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "OutlookPlugin",
            });               
            //give list of files
                var items = service.Files.List().Execute().Items;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to send an authentication header with your web request. I have my own open source lightweight library that simplifies working with files on Google Drive: https://github.com/AlexeyVlg/Pranas.Net.Clouds You do not need to use it, but in this library you can find the examples on how to get an authorization token using RestSharp library: https://github.com/AlexeyVlg/Pranas.Net.Clouds/blob/master/Pranas.Client.GoogleDrive/Business/Auth/DriveAuthorization.cs. Just download the C# WPF example and try it out.
Please remember to specify your AppClientId, AppClientSecret and AppClientRedirectUri in DriveAuthData class to use this example.
You can read more about authorization at: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-auth.